# Rearrange columns based on headers

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to rearrange the columns' order based on their header names. Is it possible to create a blank column if the column is included in the array but not on the workbook? For example, if `correctOrder() = Array("Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3", "Sample 4")` and sample 4 does not exist in the workbook, a blank column will be created.

````
Dim correctOrder() As Variant
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim headerRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim mainWS As Worksheet

Set mainWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' Edit this to be the correct order you need
correctOrder() = Array("Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Sample 3")

With mainWS
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set headerRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastCol))
End With

Dim newWS As Worksheet
Set newWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
newWS.Name = "Rearranged Sheet"

Dim col As Long
With newWS
    For col = 1 To lastCol
        For Each cel In headerRng
            If cel.Value = correctOrder(col - 1) Then
                mainWS.Columns(cel.Column).Copy .Columns(col)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cel
    Next col
End With```
````

Comment: Do you need copying the format, too? Now, where to be created that 'not found in array' column? Like the last one? And, should there be only one such a not able to be found header?

Comment: It should create the column and sort it like the others, even if the missing column is not only the last one but can also be in the middle. The format should be the same.

Comment: So, the headers order to be exactly as in `correctOrder` array, placing/letting empty columns if not a match exists. Should this understanding be correct? And you did no answer the question related to format to be copied (or not)...

Comment: Exactly. The format should also be copied

Comment: OK. I will post an answer in 2 - 3 minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub matchColumnsSh()
  Dim correctOrder(), lastCol As Long, arrHd, mainWS As Worksheet
  
  Set mainWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 ' Edit this to be the correct order you need (not existing sheetes included):
 correctOrder() = Array("Sample 1", "Sample 2", "Test1", "Sample 3", "Test2")

 With mainWS
    lastCol = .cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column
    arrHd = .Range(.cells(1, 1), .cells(1, lastCol)).Value         'place the headers in an array
 End With

Dim newWS As Worksheet
Set newWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
newWS.Name = "Rearranged Sheet"

Dim col As Long, mtch
With newWS
    For col = 1 To UBound(correctOrder) + 1                           'iterate between the array elements
        mtch = Application.match(correctOrder(col - 1), arrHd, 0)  'if a martch is found:
        If IsNumeric(mtch) Then
            mainWS.Columns(mtch).Copy .Columns(col)                'copy the matched column in its place
        Else
            .cells(1, col).Value = correctOrder(col - 1)                   'only write the column header
        End If
    Next col
 End With
End Sub
```